# What is the best programming language to do crypto running time measurement?

Tags: algorithms, c, cryptography, measurement

I am trying to measure the running time of different crypto algorithm. e.g. how long it takes to encrypt/decrypt a block of plaintext. May I ask if `C` with `OpenSSL` is the best PL to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far, the language question is a matter of fashion. The best language for getting stuff done is the one you know. The best language for personal development is one you don't.

`C` would work just fine.

Comment: its not really an answer to the question, but i guess this is what i need to hear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The same (both PL and library) that you'd use for production because libraries differ in implementation details, and benchmark from one PL/library is not representative of performance with another PL.